# How to import UIAutomation files in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import the `UIAutomation` files in `PowerShell` from this site

> https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=uiautomation

But when I download there are no `.dll` files. How can I use programs such as `Inspect.exe` to automate the `UI` in `PowerShell`?

I am following steps from this site

> https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/desktop-application-ui-automation-with-powershell/

Comment: I wouldn't know how to use it, but if you unzip the download and look in the `releases` folder you'll find a json file describing what's inside the numbered subfolders. These folders contain files that are actually .zip files where all .`dll's` are in for that specific build. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, files are there but they don't have any extension. How I am supposed to use it?

`https://ibb.co/fcp3go`

Comment: simply add the .zip extension to them and unpack

Comment: Yeah figured it out... Thanks by the way...

Comment: @adj009 i see atleast 5 zip included in each releases? what is relevance of each zip and how to decide which dlls to be included? if i dont need all functionalities.

Comment: some folders contain only .ps1 scripts. some contain full bundle. I use the folder starting with '93a' in release 44. others I haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

The downloaded zip contains 6 items, one among which is the **releases** folder. You'll find a *releaseList.json* file under it.

Now, the file isn't so clear but, let's say you want to use the file with .Net framework 4 and the release **0.8.7 Beta 3**, just scroll down to the bottom, and under the ID: 44, you have 5 entries with the *FileName* as:

- UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.NET35.zip
- UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.NET40.zip
- UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.for.ModernUI.zip
- UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.sources.zip
- UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.samples.zip

Decide which one you need as per your requirements - I selected ***UIAutomation.0.8.7B3.NET40.zip***. Now, check its corresponding *URL* and that should tell you which file you need to look for.

For the one I used, the *URL* is: *./**44**/**e1bf995a-f3c9-453d-88bc-0ff6d3509820***, hence you'd need to go back to the *releases* folder and then browse for the folder labeled **44** and find the file named ***e1bf995a-f3c9-453d-88bc-0ff6d3509820***.

Open the said file with a zip viewer and extract its content and here is where you find the **UiAutomation.dll** file. Use **Import-Module** with the path of the extracted files location and you should be good to go.